# Nuxt Content : QueryBuilderParams with where condition not working

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt-content

So I have this `nuxt-content` project with several articles available in the `/content/news` folder.

I have a `/pages/news/index.vue` page with `<ContentList />` inside, it works fine.

But I want to plug filter features on this page, eg. `/news?author=myauthor` or `/news?tag=mytag`.

So I went for `<ContentList :query="query">` as per [the docs](https://content.nuxtjs.org/api/components/content-list#query-example).

If I set as a query:

```
import type { QueryBuilderParams } from "@nuxt/content/dist/runtime/types";
const query: QueryBuilderParams = {
  path: "/news",
  limit: 5,
  sort: [{ date: -1 }],
};
```

I get this [API call](http://localhost:5000/api/_content/query?_params=%7B%22where%22:%5B%7B%22_path%22:%22--REGEX+/%5E%5C%5C/news/%22%7D%5D,%22sort%22:%5B%7B%22date%22:-1%7D%5D,%22limit%22:5%7D) which returns (along with other results):

```
[
  {
    "_path": "/news/2023-02-17-welcome-to-our-new-website",
    "_dir": "news",
    "_draft": false,
    "_partial": false,
    "_locale": "",
    "_empty": false,
    "title": "Welcome to our new website",
    "description": "I am delighted to introduce my new website with news releases publishing feature.",
    "cover": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1461749280684-dccba630e2f6?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb",
    "createdAt": "2023-02-20T13:26:00.000Z",
    "draft": false,
    "publishedAt": "2023-02-17T00:00:00.000Z",
    "author": "My name",
    "auth": "aslugifiedname",
    "tags": [
      {
        "name": "news",
        "color": "green"
      }
    ],
    "body": {
      "type": "root",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "element",
          "tag": "p",
          "props": {},
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "value": "I am delighted to introduce my new website with news releases publishing feature."
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "toc": {
        "title": "",
        "searchDepth": 2,
        "depth": 2,
        "links": []
      }
    },
    "_type": "markdown",
    "_id": "content:news:2023-02-17-welcome-to-our-new-website.md",
    "_source": "content",
    "_file": "news/2023-02-17-welcome-to-our-new-website.md",
    "_extension": "md"
  },
]
```

(notice the `"auth": "aslugifiedname"` prop).

But if I change the query to:

```
import type { QueryBuilderParams } from "@nuxt/content/dist/runtime/types";
const query: QueryBuilderParams = {
  path: "/news",
  where: [{ auth: "aslugifiedname" }],
  // where: [{ auth: { $eq: "aslugifiedname" } }], // I also tried this version
  limit: 5,
  sort: [{ date: -1 }],
};
```

I get `[]` as a result.

What am I doing wrong? Why cant' I filter over this field? I thought it could be related to spaces so I tried with the slugified version, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Might be silly, but have you tried to avoid the brackets in the `where` clause?

```
const query: QueryBuilderParams = { path: '/collab', where: { published: { $eq: true } }, limit: 15, sort: [{ authorship: -1 }] }

const { data: publishedQuery } = await useAsyncData('published', () => {
  return queryContent('/collab').where({ published: true }).sort({ authorship: -1 }).find()
})
```

If I keep the brackets, I also get a [].
Without them, I get the expected results

Interesting that my IDE is complaining about the syntax, but the documentation in the code itself shows it should be valid.

[dummy compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiCzd.png)

[QueryBuilderWhere declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aT6y.png)